# I'm trying to understand the following code in a Spring application that references a "target" property with System.getenv()

Tags: java, spring, maven

I can't see how and when this "target" property will be created. I have saved and printed out the return of the `System.getenv()` method - which is `null`. I have also built the project with a `System.out.println(System.getProperties())` call and couldn't find any "target" property.

I'm starting to think this might be a code smell or am I missing something?

```java
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        App app = new App();
        app.bootStrap();
    }

    private void bootStrap() {

        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles(getProfile());
        ctx.load(Config.SPRING_CONFIG);
        ctx.refresh();

        Controller controller = ctx.getBean(LoginController.class);
        controller.init();
    }
    
    private String getProfile() {

        String target = System.getenv(Config.SPRING_PROFILE_ENV_VAR);
        return target == null ? Config.SPRING_DEFAULT_PROFILE : target;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Config {

    public static final String SPRING_CONFIG = "/spring/spring-config.xml";
    public static final String SPRING_DEFAULT_PROFILE = "dev";
    public static final String SPRING_PROFILE_ENV_VAR = "target";
}
```

```xml
<project>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.196</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.10</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>org.example.placeholder.App</mainClass>
                        </transformer>

                        <!-- Make sure multiple spring jars do not override exiting META-INF -->
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                        </transformer>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                        </transformer>

                    </transformers>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations" value="classpath:javabank.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <import resource="persistence.xml"/>
    <import resource="services.xml"/>
    <import resource="presentation.xml"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: can you please share the content of "/spring/spring-config.xml"

Comment: @mcvkr Hi, just posted the content of "/spring/spring-config.xml". Not sure if I should post the content of those imports but if you need those as well, just let me know.

Comment: `System.getProperties` is a totally different set of properties as `System.getenv` us using. ALso what is your question actually? If the environment variable isn't set it returns a default value, so I'm not sure which code-smell you are talking about.

Comment: @M.Deinum - My question is: Does a "target" property exist in either the environment context or any other context that is relative to the code and is it a good practice to define this property just to return a null value?

Comment: Do you actually understand environment properties? Those are properties set at the OS level (windows properties or EXPORT with a linux based one).. `System.getenv` returns `null` why would that be wrong behavior?It is a class from the JDK itself.